# Invalid Operation Setting Result Set Object VBA

Tags: vba, runtime-error, invalidoperationexception

Hi Maybe someone can enlighten me here. Using VBA code and I want to include a check for zero record count from a query and it now fails at the code I added where it was fine before. Code below shows set up:

```
Sub MySub()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb()
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim sqlQry As String
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

sqlQry = "My Query String"


If DLookup("Name", "MSysObjects", "Name= 'QueryName1'") <> "" Then
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("QueryName1")
qdf.SQL = sqlQry
Else
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("QueryName1", sqlQry)
End If

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(qdf.Name) << FAILS HERE
If rst.RecordCount <> 0 Then
DoCmd.OpenQuery (qdf.Name)
Else
MsgBox "no data returned"
Exit Sub
End If

Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

It fails on the line shown above with run "time error 3219 Invalid Operation". the only thing I changed is added an object reference for business objects for another part of the code, not this part. It ran fine before and only other change is start of a new sub below this code but running only this bit code (not the whole module) in debug mode it came up with the error.

Comment: After you create the querydef, can you print out the name?  e.g. msgbox qdf.name?  Also, if the SQL is invalid, the query def might not be created which could cause the error

Comment: @cardmagik Yes I can print the name out with: MsgBox "Query name = " & qdf.Name - I also tried running the existing Access query in the DB, the query this code create last time I ran it, and it never fell over.

Comment: Sometimes errors pop up in different places and don't make sense.  When I get weird errors, from the VBA menu, I use Debug > Compile (your project name).  This sometimes helps.  Also, can you tell if it's your "if" or "else" statement failing or do both fail?